# How to create a dialog in a specific location with fullcalendar io

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'd like to create a small modal window with different text fields just like in the image below.

I can create a modal with fullcalendar io, but I'm not sure how to arrange it so it pops up just under the day like in the image. How would this be accomplished and would it be a modal window or JQuery Dialog box, or ???

Looking at the doc for full calendar io I see the coordinates can be pulled from a dayClick or eventClick event, but these are x, y coordinates from the screen, how would that translate into an area under the day box shown below? Or is there another way to calculate this place to put the window?

[image]

Here is a modal that can be displayed but its shown in the middle of the screen. Which isn't what I want.

```js
dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#eventTitle').val("");
    $('#eventDate').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
    $('#eventTime').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'HH:mm'));
    ShowEventPopup(date); 
},

function ShowEventPopup(date) {
    ClearPopupFormValues();
    $('#popupEventForm').show();
    $('#eventTitle').focus(); 
}
```

```html
<div id="popupEventForm" class="modal hide" style="display: none;">
   <div class="modal-header"><h3>Add new event</h3></div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="EventForm" class="well">
        <input type="hidden" id="eventID">
        <label>Event title</label>
        <input type="text" id="eventTitle" placeholder="Title here"><br />
        <label>Scheduled date</label>
        <input type="text" id="eventDate"><br />
        <label>Scheduled time</label>
        <input type="text" id="eventTime"><br />
        <label>Appointment length (minutes)</label>
        <input type="text" id="eventDuration" placeholder="15"><br />
    </form>
</div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="btnPopupCancel" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnPopupSave" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Save event</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this not the same question than your other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268178/creating-a-small-custom-modal-window-under-the-day-slot-in-full-calendar-io ?

Comment: yes. I'm going to delete the other question.

Comment: Modal means something in the center of the screen that usually greys out the rest of the screen. You want a dialogue that isn't a modal. You could also call it a tooltip.